# SIGSEGV segmentation fault with regards to the pwd.c file?

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


uid_t userIdFromName(char *name)
{
    struct passwd* pwd;
    

    pwd=getpwnam(name);
    if(pwd==NULL)
    {
        perror("gepwnam\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return pwd->pw_uid;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    uid_t uid;
    int totalEntries=0;
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* newFile;
    char strUID[65];
    if(argc<1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"The format is: %s name",argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    uid=userIdFromName(argv[1]);
    dir=opendir("/proc/");
    sprintf(strUID,"%d",uid);
    
    while((readdir(dir))!=NULL)
    {
        totalEntries++;
    }
    
    char* dirNames[1000];
    char* dirIds[1000];
    int newCount=0;
    dir=opendir("/proc/");


    while((newFile=readdir(dir))!=NULL)
    {
        
        char statusFilePath[65]="/proc/";
        strcat(statusFilePath,newFile->d_name);
        strcat(statusFilePath,"/status");

        FILE* statusFile=fopen(statusFilePath,"r");//one of the file has been opened;
        size_t size;
        char* lineData;
        

        if(statusFile==NULL)
        continue;
        
        int currentPoisition=0;
        while((getline(&lineData,&size,statusFile))!=-1)
        {
            
            
            if(strncmp("Uid:",lineData,strlen("Uid:"))==0)
            {   
                
                char* dataLine;
                currentPoisition=ftell(statusFile);
                fseek(statusFile,0,SEEK_SET);
                

                if(strstr(lineData,strUID)!=NULL)
                {
                    
                    
                    int forName=0,forPid=0;
                    while((getline(&dataLine,&size,statusFile))!=-1)
                    {
                        
                        
                        if(strncmp("Name:",dataLine,strlen("Name:"))==0)
                        {
                            printf("%s\n",dataLine);
                            dirNames[newCount]=dataLine;
                            forName=1;
                           

                        }

                        if(strncmp("Pid:",dataLine,strlen("Pid:"))==0)
                        {
                            printf("%s\n",dataLine);
                            dirIds[newCount]=dataLine;
                            forPid=1;
                        }

                        if(forName==1&&forPid==1)
                        {
                            newCount++;
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                fseek(statusFile,0,SEEK_SET);
                fseek(statusFile,currentPoisition,SEEK_SET);
            }

        }
        
    }


   /* int runner=0;
    while(runner<newCount)
    printf("%s\n",dirNames[runner++]);*/
}
```

I have been unable to understand the core-dumps generated for this program.The program crashes halfway. Here is the core-dump info:

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f4ed8699d9c in _nss_files_getpwnam_r (name=0x0, result=0x7f4ed8896140 , buffer=0x559f75c7e2a0 "root", buflen=1024, errnop=0x7f4ed889a4c0) at nss_files/files-pwd.c:32
32      nss_files/files-pwd.c: No such file or directory.

I thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe this: `getline(&lineData,&size,statusFile))` require that `lineData` needs to be given memory and an address before using like this...

Answer (score 1):

Have you qualified the contents of `argv[1]` before using it here?

```
uid=userIdFromName(argv[1]);
```

Also, among other issues, using a variable created as:

```
char* lineData;
```

in a function such as:

```
while((getline(&lineData,&size,statusFile))!=-1)
```

Will likely cause a `seg-fault`, as you are attempting to write to a location that you do not own.

Same for:

```
char *dataLine;
...
while((getline(&dataLine,&size,statusFile))!=-1)
```

etc.

Create memory and an address for these (and any other like them) before using.

eg:

```
 size_t size = 1000;
 char *lineData  = malloc(size*(sizeof(*lineData));
 if(lineDate)
 {
     //continue to use lineData 
     free(lineData);//when done using it 
     ...
```

Comment: It's the same with malloc. That, I assumed, happens due to the fact that free actually doesn't free memory. I've been using controlled data and setting argv[1] to the username that will be accepted.